# jQuery - update 2 or more form fields with the same data

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

Ok so it sounds confusing... but in essence what im trying to do should make sense.

I am using jquery tabs.  In these tabs I have some lists and some form fields.

so...

**Tab a = list a with some form fields... 
Tab b = list b with formfields... and so on.**

BUT... one of these tabs is an **ALL tab**.  and it contains ListA **and** List B etc etc.

So my question is this.

If a user updates  TAB A (list A) 
How can I get TAB C (all lists)  to update with the same value?

Hope that makes sense.

Thanks in advance 
W

Comment: i would think that the Tab would need a listener, such as an onChange event... and then when TabA changes, TabC updates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of tabs with one input and a tab with all of them.  A change to any of the inputs is automatically (on the `keyup` event) sent to the copy (even if you make the change on the 'All' tab ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dAhLj/)):

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-4">All</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
        <p>
            A:<input name='A' />
        </p>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2">
        <p>
            B:<input name='B' />
        </p>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-3">
        <p>
            C:<input name='C' />
        </p>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-4">
        <p>
            A:<input name='A' /><br/>
            B:<input name='B' /><br/>
            C:<input name='C' /><br/>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
$(function () {
    $("#tabs").tabs();
    $('input[name=A],input[name=B],input[name=C]').on('keyup change', function() {
        $('input[name='+$(this).attr('name')+']').val($(this).val());
    })
});
</script>
```

Comment: the example is precisely what I was trying to achieve.  Thank you for taking the time to create the fiddle.